# ocd assertion fault when connecting gdb

Tags: openocd

I am debugging board STM32f4 Discovery on Ubuntu 20.04 with openocd and arm-none-eabi-none. Things work well until yesterday. Today, when I connect the gdb to localhost:4444, following assertion happened and ocd quit:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v37 API v2 SWIM v26 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 2.894743
Info : stm32f4x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x100f6413
Info : flash size = 8194kbytes
openocd: src/flash/nor/stm32f2x.c:990: stm32x_probe: Assertion `(bank->size >> 10) == flash_size_in_kb' failed.
```

I see that it is using stm32f2x.c, is it correct since the chip is stm32f407vgt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: I scale up the clock speed without switching to appropriate Flash Latency so the debugger will lose the track of program address as mentioned here, in Clocks and initial settings part:
https://vjordan.info/log/fpga/first-steps-with-the-stm32f4.html